# Can't add popular namespaces references to C# .DLL Class Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**My question in simple few lines:**

I'm trying to build a compiled .dll C# Class Library that contains functions I want to easily call from other non-C# applications.

My functions depend on popular namespaces' *Assemblies* references like `System.Windows.Forms` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote`.

When I try to add any of them to my class library, I get `does not exist in the namespace` error.
Also, they don't exist in *Reference Manager* (Screenshot 2).

---

**Continued description:**

Within normal C# application (that's compiled to .exe), I can easily include those Assemblies references using code lines like below:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;              // works good in normal application
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote;
```

Also I am able to add *References* with *References Manager* (by right clicking the References node on *Solution Explorer* → then Select *Add Reference* → then search for the references I want to add) — in Visual Studio 2019 (Screenshot 1). I can find and add assemblies like `System.Windows.Forms` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote` easily.

**But** within a C# Class Library (that's compiled to .dll), when I try to include `System.Windows.Forms` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote` using the below lines:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;              // gives errors in C# Class Library
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote;
```

I get errors:

```
CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  MyLibrary  C:\Path\to\MyLibrary\Class1.cs
CS0234The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  OneNoteLibrary  C:\Path\to\MyLibrary\Class1.cs  15  Active
```

Also, these assemblies aren't shown at all when I try to add using *References Manager* (Screenshot 2).

---

***Screenshot 1:***
[image]

***Screenshot 2:***
[image]

***Screenshot 3***:
[image]

Comment: What I need to scroll down? I get screenshot 2 when I work on C# class library project where there's nothing to scroll.

Comment: What is the project type of MyLibrary? I can't reproduce the issue when creating Class Library (.Net Framework) on my pc, I see first screenshot and can add reference to winforms.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes I create Class Library (.Net Framework). I have also included screenshot of Solution Explorer (screenshot 3)

Comment: That's not a framework library, that looks to be either Core or Standard.

Comment: You probably need to know which type of class library you are working on first, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff Then each of the types has its own limitation on which namespaces/references are possible. WinForms and Office API is not available unfortunately for majority of the class library types.

Comment: @gilliduck True. Problem is now solved by selecting Class Library (.NET Framework) :) The problem was that I mistakenly selected Class Library (.NET Standard), which I didn't notice because it has similar title.